# Why when I try to change user I obtain this error message? "myusername is not in the sudoers file"

Tags: bash, permissions, sudo, users

I am not so into Linux and I have the following problem.

I have to change user (using a given user) on a Linux server.

So I use the

```
[myusername@myserver~]$ sudo -i -u otherusername
[sudo] password for myusername:
myusername is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.
[myusername@myserver~]$
```

So it seems that I have not permission to do it or something like this. What extactly is the problem?

Comment: do you have the passwort of *otherusername*? Then you could use `su otherusername` without sudo

Comment: @Wayne_Yux No I have not. I think that the sysadmin have to enable my user on the sudoers file. Is it? I want to be sure before ask and make a fool

Comment: If you dont know the password of root user then you can't change your user as admin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't administer the server, ask your sysadmins to add you to `sudoers`. Or ask them to perform the administrative task for you.

(On behalf of sysadmins everywhere, please be sure to specify exactly what privileges you need, *why* you need them, and the authorization you have for them.)